# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, import-from-excel

When I am adding foll. code but on server its showing error.
Code -

```
 object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass xl = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlBook;
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlSheet;
                        xlBook = (Workbook)xl.Workbooks.Open(docPath, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing);
                        xlSheet = (Worksheet)xlBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
                        xlSheet.Name = "Sheet1";
                        xlBook.Save();
                        xl.Application.Workbooks.Close();
```

Error -

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have added reference of "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel" dll in webApplication.
In local its working fine. 
Note : In server microsoft Office is not installed.
Can any one solve this issue without any installation on server.

Comment: Nope.. you need office installed

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel** without installing excel. But you can use [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) instead on the server